# Copy document id so it can be part of the field

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want my firestore collection to be like below (where during/after importing, the document id is also part of the field **docID**)

```
Collection    |   document          |    field
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Test          |   Wekfan12kfad      |    name:  Bob Larry Joe III   
                                    |    docID: Wekfan12kfad
```

I imported a csv file to firestore using this python [script](https://medium.com/@wenxuan0923/upload-data-to-firebase-cloud-firestore-with-10-line-of-python-code-1877690a55c6)

My attempt for importing

```
import pandas as pd
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

# Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
cred = credentials.Certificate('./serviceAccountkey.json')

# Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'databaseURL': 'https://hi.firebaseio.com/'})

db = firestore.client()

#refers to the collection name 
doc_ref = db.collection(u'test')
#refer to the doc name (my attempt for retreiving id)
docID = doc_ref.document().id

# Import data
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
tmp = df.to_dict(orient='records')
list(map(lambda x: doc_ref.add(x), tmp))

#not sure if I need to use .add to add the doc id into the field
```

With the script above it imports everything in the csv into the firestore based on the columns given in the file.

Is there a way to add the document id to also be part of the field?

Comment: Please don't link to external code.  Copy the code you're using into the question itself, and show that you made an attempt at solving the problem, explaining what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson my bad! I added my code of what I had and what I tried but when I run it, there's no errors but it doesn't show what I want on firestore